# how to write a regex in Matlab to select part of a string?

Tags: regex, string, matlab

Given these strings:

```
var-nvar-ar var-nvar-br var-int-ar var-int-br oth-nvar-ar oth-nvar-br oth-int-ar oth-int-br
```

I would like to write a regex that selects all the strings that contain my substring if the substring is:

between the beginning of string and `-`

or

between `-` and `-`

or

between `-` and the end of the string

So if `substring = 'var'` then the regex would select

```
var-nvar-ar var-nvar-br var-int-ar var-int-br
```

I tried:

```
strings = {'var-nvar-ar' 'var-nvar-br' 'var-int-ar' 'var-int-br' 'oth-nvar-ar' 'oth-nvar-br' 'oth-int-ar' 'oth-int-br'}

regexp(strings,'[^|(*?-)]var[(-.*)|$]','match')
```

but the result wasn't what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an OR operation (`|`), a.k.a. [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), it needs to be inside of a sub-expression `()` rather than a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[]`.  Instead of,

```
regexp(strings,'[^|(*?-)]var[(-.*)|$]','match')
```

use

```
regexp(strings,'(^|(*?-))var((-.*)|$)','match','once')
```